# MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS ON CREATE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am creating a table and I ran into an error that mentioned that I am missing a right parenthesis.

I have looked through my script and I realised that there is nothing missing.

```
create table lalala as (
select distinct tc.riser_fid, tc.cbl_fid AS ZH_CBL_FID, FH.CABLE_NO AS ZH_CABLE_NO, FCH2.CHANNEL_SEQ_NO AS ZH_STRAND_NO, 
fmh.facility_id as ZH_FACILITY_ID, tc.cbl_ownership AS ZH_CBL_OWNERSHIP, FMG.FACILITY_ID AS ZG_FACILITY_ID, 
FMG.FACILITY_NAME AS ZG_FACILITY_NAME, FCG1.CHANNEL_SEQ_NO AS ZG_STRAND_NO,ft2.A_SITE_ID as A_SITE_ID, ft2.B_SITE_ID as B_SITE_ID
from sgtel10.total_cables tc
join gc_fcbl_temp FH ON FH.G3E_FID = tc.cbl_fid and fh.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
left join facility_master_temp fmh on fmh.facility_name  = fh.cable_no
left join facility_master_temp fmh on fmh.facility_name || 'P' = fh.cable_no
left join facility_master_temp fmh on fmh.facility_name || 'A' = fh.cable_no
left join facility_master_temp fmh on fmh.facility_name || 'Z' = fh.cable_no
left join facility_master_temp fmh on fmh.facility_name || 'AP' = fh.cable_no
join facility_channel_temp fch2 on fch2.facility_id = fmh.facility_id and fch2.CHANNEL_REF IS NOT NULL
left JOIN FACILITY_TRAIL_ITEMS_TEMP ft on ft.facility_trail_itm_id = fch2.facility_trail_itm_id
left JOIN FACILITY_TRAIL_ITEMS_TEMP ft2 on ft2.parent_fac_trl_itm_id = ft.parent_fac_trl_itm_id and ft2.trail_seq_no = 1.0
left join facility_channel_temp FCG1 ON FCG1.CHANNEL_ID = ft2.asgn_channel_id and FCG1.CHANNEL_SEQ_NO IS NOT NULL
left join facility_master_temp fmg on fmg.facility_id = fcg1.facility_id 
order by fmh.facility_id, FCH2.CHANNEL_SEQ_NO
);
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error?

Comment: Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` clause makes no sense, and actually might be the source of the error.  So, try removing it.  The reason `ORDER BY` makes no sense is that SQL tables are inherently unordered.  `ORDER BY` only is appropriate when selecting and presenting from a table.

**Edit:** `ORDER BY` might make sense if you were using Oracle's `FETCH` syntax to select only a certain number of rows in such order.  But, as your query is *not* doing that, `ORDER BY` is therefore out of place.

Comment: `ORDER BY` might also make sense when a (sub)query limits the results